# react-native Link - repeated invocations keep appending to configuration files

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking

React Native Link appears not to parse the previous changes to configurations files, and instead makes incremental, repetitive changes.

For instance, `android/app/build.gradle` starts with:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  compile project(':react-native-cookie')
}
```

After first invocation of `react-native link`

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  compile project(':react-native-cookie')
  compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  compile project(':react-native-cookie')
}
```

After second invocation...

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  compile project(':react-native-cookie')
  compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  compile project(':react-native-cookie')
  compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  compile project(':react-native-cookie')
}
```

And so on..

Any good place to start my investigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey your answer is there : [react-native link causes duplicate imports in Android settings.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032841/react-native-link-causes-duplicate-imports-in-android-settings-gradle)

It is currently in PR and being tested.

Comment: Somehow my search skills have failed me yesterday. Good shout!